# Monitor for UUID+Major with Kontakt.io SDK

Tags: ios, ibeacon

According to the description at [1] I thought it is possible to monitor for UUID+major with the Kontakt.io SDK:

How can you monitor for UUID+major with the Kontakt.io SDK, not only UUID? This should be possible according to:

> A region can be defined by proximity UUID only, a UUID plus Major
>   value, a UUID plus Major and Minor values. You can select the level of
>   granularity you need.

But a KTRegion has only a uuid property. My expectation would be that there is a majorId property within the KTRegion class. But that just doesn't exist.

Btw, I know how to monitor with the iOS location manager. This won't be an answer to the question.

[1] http://kontakt.io/blog/beacon-id-strategy-guide-quick-deployment/

Answer (score 0):

Somehow there is a mistake in Kontakt.io's documentation, sorry for that. Atm you can't set major and minor values in KTKRegion object.

That said, it's not that big deal to achieve the same effect.
You have to add condition in delegate's method **- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons** to filter ranged beacons by needed minor and minor.

To be honest this is similar how it's done with CLBeaconRegion under the hood.

Comment: Well, that's bad. Very bad indeed. I can't properly get background beacon entry / exit notifications then using Kontakt.io. It effectively means I'm limited to monitor max 20 regions when the app is in the background, instead of virtually infinit when I reuse majors and place beacons so that they are far away enough from each other.

Comment: See also: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html. Is there any chance you can add this quickly, I understand you work for Kontakt.io? It should be rather simple.

Comment: First thing first, even if this will be possible, like with CLBeaconRegion, still you can monitor max 20 regions.
"Regions are a shared system resource, and the total number of regions available systemwide is limited. For this reason, Core Location limits to 20 the number of regions that may be simultaneously monitored by a single app." 
It's not that bad as you claimed because I gave you a quick solution for this.
I don't know why you gave me -1 - I gave proper answer on your question.
Huge update of Kontakt.io's SDK will be available this week, this feature will be added as well ;)

Comment: It wasn't me actually who downvoted you ;-). I'm actually grateful for your comment here, and will give you an upvote just for this =). However, you can manage virtually infinit iBeacon regions if you setup IDs in a clever way, so that you get all region entry and region exit events for all beacons even when close to each other (similar to four-color-theorem).

Comment: Good to know that it wasn't you ;)
What do you mean by managing virtually infinite amount of regions?
Btw. new SDK is on it's way to be released.

Comment: I mean that it is possible to handle any region exit and entry events by placing iBeacons in such a way that no two major IDs are near each other. Then the app will receive all region events even for very dense iBeacon setups with many beacons in background mode, and has a few seconds time to range and get the minir ID of for the major with which the app was woken up with.

Comment: Ok now I know what you mean. Still you can only add 20 Region defining objects to CoreLocation.